# How do you treat replicates for ordinal data?

Tags: ordinal-data, descriptive-statistics

Let's say I have a set of tumors, and I ask two pathologists to rate it on a scale of 1 through 5, 1 being the most benign, and 5 being the most aggressive. The data sends up looking like:

```
          Pathologist 1     Pathologist 2
Tumor A   1                 2
Tumor B   3                 4
Tumor C   1                 4
Tumor D   5                 4
Tumor E   3                 3
```

I'd consider the judgement of both pathologists to be equal -- i.e. they are essentially replicate readings for each tumor. For continuous data, replicates are simply combined into a mean with a standard deviation. However, how would one "combine" replicates for ordinal data?

---

Edit: A little more detail on the analysis:  Each pathologist gives a descriptive measure on a number of characteristics that are all rated from 1 through 5. Each tumor is then sub-typed into five distinct categories. I then want to describe each category of tumor across each characteristic (which has two replicate readings). So the table looks more like this:

```
Tumor     Subtype     C1-1  C1-2  C2-1  C2-2  C3-1  C3-2
Tumor A   Group A        1     2     2     2     1     1
Tumor B   Group A        3     2     4     4     2     2
Tumor C   Group B        1     2     3     2     3     1
Tumor D   Group B        2     2     5     5     3     3
Tumor E   Group C        4     3     2     2     4     3
```

where C1, C2, C3... is a different characteristics/measurements and `-1`, `-2` are replicate readings. How can I properly combine `C1-1` and `C1-2` to get a "composite" score for `C1`?

Comment: How can you say that the judgement of both pathologists is equal?  The data here says otherwise (e.g. Pathologist 1 rated Tumor C a 1, while pathologist 2 rated it a 4).  This directly contradicts what you say is the case.

Comment: Why not use both values? (In fact, I would recommend that in the continuous case as well.) What is it you want to do w/ these data?

Comment: @StatsStudent I mean that I consider the diagnostic ability of both pathologists to be equal, i.e. I trust them equally (the example I illustrated is a little extreme) -- in the actual data, most replicates agree with each other, but I'm wondering what to do in the instances they don't agree.

Comment: @gung The actual analysis is a bit more complicated. Each pathologist gives a descriptive measure on a number of characteristics that are all rated from 1 through 5. Each tumor is then sub-typed into five distinct categories. I then want to describe each category of tumor across each characteristic (which has two replicate readings).

Comment: That's a bit hard to follow. Are these ratings the response variable in the final model? Are you just using the ratings (w/ other info) to cluster the tumors, & the cluster assignments will be response in the final model? Are these predictor variables?

Comment: @gung The clusters have been assigned from other available data. We're interested in seeing if different clusters have different frequencies of each characteristic. For example is there a significant difference in distribution in characteristic C1 across group A, group B, and group C tumors? We do that for each characteristic down the line.

Comment: OK, so you're trying to combine them into *predictors*. Are the subtypes ordered (eg, A<B<C...)? How many tumors are there total? Are you willing to assume that the ratings are approximately equal interval, or if not, do you have any reasonable sense how widely spread each ordered interval is?

Comment: @gung The subtypes are purely categorical. Around ~68 samples total. The actual data has only two subtypes (basically a yes/no criteria re: "aggressiveness" derived from other metadata). The ratings are not weighted equally -- e.g. scored 0 if <1% of tumors showed reactivity, scored 1 if 1-10% showed reactivity, 2 for 10-40%, 3 for 50%+

Comment: The example data show (at least) 3 subcategories `A`, `B`, & `C`. If you have only 2 (say `A` & `B`), you can use logistic regression methods. You could enter both as separate covariates or add 2 lines of data for each tumor (as repeated measures) in a generalized linear mixed effects model.